# How to make js generated elements interact properly with static html elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Js student here.

I have made an example [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/vaggelis-magonezos/pen/VwKPKdp).

In this test case,as you can see in the above code **on the right side** i have 6 hardcoded html inputs,3 for first name and 3 for last name.
On the left side i have a `<button>` which is called **ADD**,and with every click of this button (with a maximum of 3 clicks) the `function addInputs()` generates a `<li>`element inside `<ol id="originContainer"></ol>`.

This generated `<li>` element contains 2 html inputs,one for the first name and one for the last name,every generated input gets a unique id using a counter variable (`var inputscounter=0;`).

The goal is to copy dynamically,whatever i type in the generated inputs -to the left- to the hardcoded ones -to the right-,first name to first name,last name to last name,all that by using the `function changeValues()` which runs with every **keyup** of the generated inputs.

**My problem is**,the `function changeValues()` works fine **but only after i generate all 3 of the elements** ( As its visualized in [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dW3Nz.jpg) picture ) on the left,but not with just one of them,or 2 ( like [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRsl0.jpg) )

What am i missing ?

Answer (score 1):

When you try to get the value of an element that is not created yet, the function throws an error. That is, in your `changeValue` function where you try to get the `value` attribute on `FnameX` when it is `undefined` (since it can't find the element in the DOM). Same for adding the click handlers on undefined elements.

You could fix that by either checking if `Fname1` etc are defined before you try to get their value.

A nicer approach would be to store in an array which elements you have generated so far. Then loop over those elements and transfer its values.

You can either store an array of ids you can use to find an element when you don't need to access them that often. In this case I would store the objects themselves.

Also you don't have to add click handlers on every element, every time you add one.

Comment: i see.thanks for helping
i am not asking for free code or anything but could you provide me an example on how would i store the appended elements to an array ?